# Show that $\int\limits_a^b |f(t)|dt \leq (b-a)\int\limits_a^b|f'(t)|dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Suppose $f(a) = 0$. Show that
>   $$
> \int\limits_a^b|f(t)|dt \leq (b-a)\int\limits_a^b|f'(t)|dt
> $$

By the mean value theorem, for every $t\in[a,b]$, there exists $c\in[a,t]$ such that
$$
\frac{f(t) - f(a)}{t-a} = f'(c) \Rightarrow f(t) = (t-a)f'(c) \leq (b-a)f'(c)
$$

So basically, I have that $f(t) \leq (b-a)f'(c)$. But $c$ depends on $t$, so I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the mean value theorem is a no-go here. If you start with (just the fundamental theorem of calculus)
$$
f(t)=f(a)+\int_a^t f'(s)\,ds=\int_a^t f'(s)\,ds,
$$
you find with the triangle inequality that
$$
|f(t)|\leq \int_a^t |f'(s)|\,ds.
$$
Next, integrate this inequality from $a$ to $b$:
$$
\int_a^b |f(t)|\,dt\leq \int_a^b\int_a^t |f'(s)|\,ds\,dt.
$$
In the final integral, change order of integration and estimate $(b-s)\leq(b-a)$. I leave that part to you.

Comment: I cannot use change of integration order, but I think it is not needed - the integrand is positive, hence $F(t) = \int\limits_a^t|f'(s)|ds$ is an increasing function of $t$, and therefore $F(t) \leq F(b)$ and we are done.

Comment: That is an even better argument! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

For $a\le x\le b$, define

$$F(x)=(x-a)\int_a^x|f'(t)|dt-\int_a^x|f(t)|dt$$

Note that $F(a)=0$ and

$$F'(x)=\int_a^x|f'(t)|dt+(x-a)|f'(x)|-|f(x)|\ge\int_a^x|f'(t)|dt-|f(x)|$$

But, since $f(a)=0$, we have $f(x)=f(x)-f(a)=\int_1^xf'(t)dt$, hence

$$|f(x)|=\left|\int_a^xf'(t)dt\right|\le\int_a^x|f'(t)|dt$$

which implies $F'(x)\ge0$ for $a\le x\le b$, which, in turn, implies $F(b)\ge F(a)=0$, and this gives the desired result.